# filepicker.io javascript api implementation

Tags: javascript, jquery, filepicker.io, filepicker

I just started to make a web in which user will upload image , instead of purchasing a extra harddisk on my server for photos . I have decided to use third party tool . I found [filepicker.io](http://filepicker.io)  quiet good amoung others . They are offering javascript api's . They also show examples in there site but these are a bit confusing . Is there any other example of complete javascript implementation .

Thanks in advance

Comment: @downvoter , Please care to explain . So that any one keeps that thing in his mind for next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out their blog its got some nice examples:
http://blog.filepicker.io/

This one in particular really helped me
http://blog.filepicker.io/post/45899334267/filepicker-io-zencoder-adding-video-to-your-app-in